# How to Fix "MySQL error message was : DBI connect failed : Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) ?"

Tags: mysql, database, vps, sqlserver, mysql-connection

I upgraded my VPS with the provider Contabo, and since then, I have been experiencing issues. Unfortunately, they have not been responsive or provided any support.

when i do command : service mysql start, it return

```
The full MySQL error message was : DBI connect failed : Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) ?
```

Command : sudo systemctl status mysql , gives:

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-10-30 03:51:56 CET; 9s ago
    Process: 4936 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 30 03:51:56 vmi891613.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Oct 30 03:51:56 vmi891613.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Oct 30 03:51:56 vmi891613.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 30 03:51:56 vmi891613.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 30 03:51:56 vmi891613.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

I tried restart "*sudo systemctl start mysql* ", but shows:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

the systemctl status mysql.service gives the same mentioned before.
if any one know how to fix this without losing my websites in the VPS, please help i have like 6 domians in this VPN and the service provider (Contabo) not helping. its been 48 hours and the financial losses continue to mount with each passing hour.

Comment: Did this used to work? What changed? What do you observe when trying to launch the mysql daemon manually from an interactive bash prompt?

Comment: is re installing mysql will help ? will it cause any damage to my website databases ?